# Add new theme for the current magento website

Tags: magento

Is it possible to add new look to the current website, without having to redo the whole thing from scratch? How? I am not very familiar with how magento works and I have no idea how to preserve all the functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's one of the big selling points of Magento.  The hierarchical theming fallback means you don't need to create a completely new theme from scratch, you can create a new theme and only add or change the parts you want to - it will fallback to your either your default package theme or the default theme (depending on how you have set it up in relation to your directory structure).  You can also add design overrides for certain time periods (ie, it loads a Christmas theme in December).

Best idea is to do a bit of reading about it as it's too broad in scope for an SO answer;

http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes